# cannot check if user is logged in from any controller other than users

Tags: cakephp

I am making a users profile page and if i route it like this

```
 Router::connect('/users/profile', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
```

then $this->Auth->user() work fine in UsersController->profile() but if iroute it like this

```
Router::connect('/pages/profile', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'profile'));
```

then it doesnt in PagesCotroller->profile() the profile function is the same in both cases

my app controller:

```
 class AppController extends Controller {
     var $components = array(
         'Auth' ,
         'Acl',
         'Session',
         'Cookie'
     );
     var $userdata = array();
     function beforeFilter(){
             $this->Auth->userModel = 'Users';

         $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array();
         $this->Auth->allow('display');
             $this->Auth->allow('index');

             var_dump($this->Auth->user());
             parent::beforeFilter();
     }
     function isAuthorized() {
        return true;
     }


}
```

and var_dump actually works if i go to /users/profile and doesnt if i go to /pages/profile
without any additional logging in or anything

$this->Auth->allow() works properly in both controllers by the way, so Auth component is available in both

here's pagescontroller

```
class PagesController extends AppController {
        var $components = array('RequestHandler');
    var $name = 'Pages';
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Session','Form','Ajax', 'Jquery');

    var $uses = array('Users');

        function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter();
            $this->Auth->allow('profile');
        }

        function beforeRender() {
            parent::beforeRender();

        }

        function profile(){

                var_dump($this->Auth->user());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer it was captcha component. It started session every time it was called and it wass called from all the controllers except users. So the user log in data was not preserved.

Comment: This is an old post, but just wanted to thank you. My app is a full blown CMS now, so it's hard to remember all the moving pieces involved and this is what it was for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Eugene,

I do wonder why you would try to achieve things like that.
The first route is already in existence, so no need to set up one.
The second route seems (imho) to be against conventions. The pages controller is used to serve more or less static pages, so I would not expect to see it routed to an action.

My two cents.

**Edit0:**
After your first comment your intentions are now more obvious:

Put

```
if ($this->Session->read(Auth.User)) ...
```

or something like this in your `page`, possibly as an element. Just check out via `debug()` what values you can read in your view/page.

**Edit1:**

1. Download and install debug_kit from
   github.
2. If the Session helper is
   enabled in the pages_controller.php,
   then you should be able to reach
   your objective.

**Edit2:**

You could check if the session is visible in other views except users. But you should definitly be aware that you are breaking CakePHP's conventions when naming a model in plural and the table alike. Unfortunatly, I cannot tell you atm if that could be relevant to the case at hand, but it is certainly something I would strive to get rid of.

Does the debug_kit show the AUTH component?

Comment: Yes you are right I can just use the users controller, basically i just put it as an example. But I still need to have the ability to check if user is logged in the pages controller, to display login form or link to profile instead of it for instance. And even if I requestAction an action in userscontroller it doesn't work. So I'm stuck.

Comment: $this->Session->read(Auth.User) sadly doesn't work. That's why I started panicking and found out $this->Auth->user() which doesnt work either :). My login form is done as an element and $session->read(Auth.User) only returns data there if rendering is done by users controller

Comment: "Does the debug_kit show the AUTH component?" no. at least i didn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if var $uses = array('Users'); 
Users should be singular, User

If this doesn't fix it... leave it singular anyway because you are calling the 'User' model.

Comment: My model is called Users and my table is called users and my controller is called UsersController, so it's allright.

Comment: what version of cake? if you baked it should be User. just curious now.

Comment: I didn't bake. I use cake for the first time. And when i have learned about baking i have already written quite a lot and didn't want to start all over. maybe i should have